# Typescript - Union Type and generic types throw incompatibility error

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, union-types

I have an issue with generic types working with union types. In my case a function is defined using a union type and when I call this function with an element of one of the types in the union I get an error I have been trying to explain for the whole day.

I managed to summarize in the following lines of code :

```
interface IA {
  a: string;
}
interface IB {
  b: string;
}
type IAll = IA | IB;

interface IG<T> {
  prop: T;
  fct: (p: T) => void;
}

function fAll(p: IG<IAll>) {
  return;
}

const a: IG<IA> = {
  prop: {a: "aaa"},
  fct: (p) => { return; }
};

fAll(a);
```

The last line `fAll(a);` returns a typing error that I just can't explain:

```
Argument of type 'IG<IA>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IG<IAll>'.
  Types of property 'fct' are incompatible.
    Type '(p: IA) => void' is not assignable to type '(p: IAll) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'p' and 'p' are incompatible.
        Type 'IAll' is not assignable to type 'IA'.
          Type 'IB' is not assignable to type 'IA'.ts(2345)
```

Why can't an element of `IA` be applied the type `IAll` while `IAll` is the union of `IA` and `IB` ? From my understanding if `IA` matches, checking for `IB` is irrelevant.

Writing `fAll(a as IG<IAll>);` fixes the issue but I don't understand why it should be necessary.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `IG<IA> | IG<IB>` is not the same as `IG<IA | IB>`. If you change your code to the first one it will work however you will not be able to call a function like that.

```
interface IA {
  a: string;
}
interface IB {
  b: string;
}
type IAll = IA | IB;

interface IG<T> {
  prop: T;
  fct: (p: T) => void;
}

function fAll(p: IG<IAll>) {
  // p.fct will allow `IA | IB` as parameters. This is not what you're looking for.
  p.fct({
    b: "string"
  })
  return;
}

const a: IG<IA> = {
  prop: {a: "aaa"},
  fct: (p) => {
    // This will log out `p.a`, but `p.a` doesn't have to be provided by `fAll` function (see above).
    console.log(p.a);
  }
};

fAll(a);

function fAllFixed(p: IG<IA> | IG<IB>) {
  // Thats better!
  p.fct({
    b: "string"
  })
  return;
}

fAllFixed(a);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIEFkG8CwAoZZOALmQGcwpQBzAbnwF99RJZEVUAhbfQgI1IUqIOo3xgAngAcO6ADZzkAXjSYAPmk708zcNHhI0AcQA8AFQB8PAsilQA9lNJnthGAjCkAFE+RmAlMpWAG72wAAm2kw6eDAAriAewPYgyDDycj6kqKYYChaBuDYA9MW2AHTuYMgA7sAKRAr2NcgABhjIGlytRGS2cFBwALYQrGTlfgAWwH0zyCD21TWTcNUS9nEA5FAocvb2ANY0afZQ5bwVVV5FhPykAERCNPcXDP4XO2BxUCBR+PgIFIUIjZXLoKwqG62By+LAkZD3OBI+4MAA0Fyq3ikgSUVihhFKUzmdQae2oyA21VaUnKcFaqOQfDiVJpdOQ4XsEDIIE21RWwRQYHsjJQdnswQiEHCjIkbXSCh68USYGSqS8ZAgKDgfHFEH85xshEBIDI9jkEHKZJ8tP8rmQ0QY2nw8sycFt-1iCSSKTSGQAYsAAB5SrLGEwYKxdXKcArWAllMwrMB9PijVgAQguNKu+MZDyeIheNjeH1G31+YhiLoDwfCXjdtCAA)

I had a similar question a while back, and got an amazingly detailed reply from jcalz (which I still don't fully understand...). I would encourage you to check that out:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58632009/5554464