# Typescript: why does a union of a function only accept an intersection of the parameter?

Tags: typescript, union, intersection

I will demonstrate my question with a simple [example](https://tsplay.dev/mbGqEW):

```
class Foo {
    foo() { }
}

class Bar {
    bar() { }
}

type FooHandler = (arg: Foo) => void;
type BarHandler = (arg: Bar) => void;

type AnyHandler = FooHandler | BarHandler;
declare var handler: AnyHandler;

handler(new Foo()); // Argument of type 'Foo' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Foo & Bar'.
```

Why does `handler` only accept the intersection `Foo & Bar` and not the union `Foo | Bar`? Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: `t3.handler` has type `((arg: Foo) => void) | ((arg: Bar) => void)`, not `(arg: Foo & Bar) => void` (although those types are strongly related to each other).  As it stands your question has little/nothing to do with conditional types. Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](//tsplay.dev/mLLb4m) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.

Comment: @jcalz this _is_ the minimal reproducible example (that I can provide). Please see [this](https://llamas.are-pretty.sexy/5ajf1T5.png) and [this](https://llamas.are-pretty.sexy/9kXDxed.png) screenshot, the same error occurs in the [playground](https://tsplay.dev/WJR25W): `Argument of type 'Foo' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Foo & Bar'.`

Comment: So, calling `t3.handler(new Foo());` is part of your problem, but was missing from the code example (that's what's needed to make it "reproducible"). And the conditional types and enums are not needed to reproduce the issue; they can be dispensed with [like this](https://tsplay.dev/w2EjzW) (this helps to make it "minimal").  Can you [edit] your question to have a genuine [mre] and then someone can answer it?

Comment: Preview of answer: unions of functions can only safely be called with intersections of parameters, support for which was [introduced in TS3.3](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types.).  Before that you couldn't even call unions of functions at all.

Comment: This has become much more minimal indeed

Comment: Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58629426/typescript-union-function-types) and its answer and see if you still need anything after that.

Comment: It seems I've been going about it the wrong way then, I'll see what I can figure out. Thanks for your help!